# How to compute a rolling sum for a grouped DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate a rolling sum by group as shown below.[image]

I tried the following:

```
# Function

john = pd.DataFrame({'name':'john',
                          'score':[0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          'rolling_sum':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0]})
                          
    joe = pd.DataFrame({'name':'joe', 
                        'score':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                        'rolling_sum':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
                        
                        
    # Merge the data
    df = pd.concat([john, joe])

df['rolling_sum'] = (
        df
        .groupby('player')
        .rolling(6, min_periods=1)
        .score
        .sum()
        .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
```

Comment: what you get from your solution? and how it differs from your expected result. Please include both. Also,  no images, add the data as a code (preferably) or as a text

Comment: The result above is an R output.

Comment: IIUC, to match the above result, you remove the min_periods

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Naveed, I have resolved my issue. Naveed advised me to remove "min_periods=1" from the code. After removing this code, I wrote a function that returns a complete DataFrame (see the code below).

## Write a function

## ----------------

```py
def calc_rolling_sum(df, window):
    """
    Compute a 6-month rolling sum.
    """
    df['rolling_sum'] = (
        df
        .groupby('player')
        .rolling(window)
        ['score']
        .sum()
        .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
    
    return df
```

## Let's test our new function

```py
aa5 = calc_rolling_sum(r.df, window=6)
```

[image]